# Pandas: if statement comparing data in 2 dataframes. If condition met, then copy the row data to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been struggling this with this problem for hours so thought I would ask for help.

I am trying to run an if statement within an `.itertuples` function where I want to select rows the `df_high` dataframe which passes both condition in my if statement when comparing to the data in my `df_today` dataframe (a df with a single line of data).

I am running a trading algorithm and am trying to see if today's high went above a previous high and then closed below it (hence the two conditions in my if statement).

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
# Create dictonary of assets
assets = ['EURUSD']

# Connect to MarketData.db
conn = db.connect("MarketData.db")
c = conn.cursor()

# DAILY REJECTION CALC PROCESS (notes) - 
#         loop: for row in rows, if todayhigh > high AND todayclose < high = TRUE, else FALSE
#         If TRUE, save df row to list >>> print list at end 

def calculate():

    validsweep = pd.DataFrame({
        'asset': pd.Series(dtype='str'),
        'date': pd.Series(dtype='str'),
        'open': pd.Series(dtype='float'),
        'high': pd.Series(dtype='float'),
        'low': pd.Series(dtype='float'),
        'close': pd.Series(dtype='float'),
        'fractal_high': pd.Series(dtype='int'),
        'fractal_low': pd.Series(dtype='int')})

    for x in assets:
        c.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {x}')
        rows = c.fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
        df = df.rename(columns={0: "date", 1: "open", 2: "high", 3: "low", 4: "close", 5: "fractal_high", 6: "fractal_low"})
        df.insert(0, 'asset', str(x))

        df_high = df[df['fractal_high'] == 1]
        df_low = df[df['fractal_low'] == 1]
        df_today = df[df['date'] == "2022-06-27"]

        for row in df_high.itertuples(index=False):
            if ((df_today['high'].iloc[0] > df_high['high']) & (df_today['close'].iloc[0] < df_high['high'])).any():
                validsweep.combine([validsweep, df_high.iloc[[row]]])
        
    return

calculate()
```

I am getting the following error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/baker/Desktop/Swing Rejection Strategy/testbed.py", line 54, in <module>
    calculate()
  File "/Users/baker/Desktop/Swing Rejection Strategy/testbed.py", line 44, in calculate
    validsweep.combine([validsweep, df_high.iloc[[row]]])
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/baker/Desktop/Swing Rejection Strategy/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1073, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/baker/Desktop/Swing Rejection Strategy/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1616, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_list_axis(key, axis=axis)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/baker/Desktop/Swing Rejection Strategy/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1587, in _get_list_axis
    return self.obj._take_with_is_copy(key, axis=axis)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/baker/Desktop/Swing Rejection Strategy/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3902, in _take_with_is_copy
    result = self._take(indices=indices, axis=axis)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/baker/Desktop/Swing Rejection Strategy/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3886, in _take
    new_data = self._mgr.take(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/baker/Desktop/Swing Rejection Strategy/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 972, in take
    else np.asanyarray(indexer, dtype=np.intp)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'EURUSD'
```

It seems an integer is being returned somewhere, but I am unsure why. I have checked and both my `validsweep` and `df_high` dataframes have the same `.dtypes` for each column.

I presume the answer to the if statement is being turned into a TRUE/FALSE integer, but I cannot figure out how to stop that happening.

Is there a way to do this so it works?

Answer (score 0):

try with index = True. As you have df_high.itertuples(index=False) in a for loop yields just named tuples. no index.
And iloc() function expects index as a parameter.

```
for row in df_high.itertuples(index=True):
```

Comment: I get the same error when I change index to True unfortunately.